# Using for loop to amend a list of variables

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I've got the below code, with the aim to run through a list of defined variables and update them.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
test_list = [a, b, c]
print(test_list)

for i in test_list:
    i = 4

print(test_list)
```

When I run this though the `test_list` variables don't change. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `test_list` is not, in any sense, a "list of defined variables".  It's simply the list `[1, 2, 3]` - the variables that those values came from are no longer relevant.

Comment: Lists don't contain *variables*. Lists contain *objects*. Variables *refer to objects*. `i = 4` just assigns an `int` object to the variable `i`, and won't affect any other variable you have.

Comment: Thanks all. Makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is returning you each element of the list, one at a time, in a variable called `i`.  So, the first time through the loop, `i` is 1.  You then change `i` to 4.  That has nothing to do with the list.

It is possible to do what you ask:

```
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    test_list[i] = 4
```

but there are usually better ways to do that kind of thing.  Tell us what you REALLY want and we can advise you.